# How can I get the last 5 element of this tax query?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, tax-query

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'news',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'order' => 'ASC',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'week',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $currweeknumber,
    )
)
);
$post = get_posts($args);
```

I have a page which posts 5 news each week. I have a problem. A year passed since I started my blog and this `$args` query shows me the last year news, not the actual. This is because week number doesn't changed at all, it's the same value from 1 to 52 (basically I have 52 terms with the value of 1,2,3...etc). Is there any way to get the last 5 element of this array, not the first 5? I'm tried with `'order' => ''DESC'` but not worked.

Comment: There's a variable here named currweeknumber, but the code that figures that out is missing, can you edit it into your question?

Comment: currweeknumber is the actual week number `$currweeknumber = date("W", strtotime("this week"));` represents the actual week as number.

Comment: hmmm then you're going to need an additional term, such as a year, or, abandon that and just use date queries and set the posts publish time correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the 'date_query' parameter to your query and include the current year.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'news',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'tax_query' => array(
     array(
      'taxonomy' => 'week',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => date("W", strtotime("this week")),
    )
  ),
  'date_query' => array(
    array(
      'year'  => date("Y")
    )
  )
);
```